# ant.echo doesn't output anything

Tags: gradle, ant

I've installed Gradle and am trying a tutorial.

My problemi is that
ant.echo doesn't print out anything

```
task helloWorld {

    doLast {

        println 'This is printed out'
        ant.echo(message: 'This is not printed out')
    }

}
```

gradle -v outputs:

---

### Gradle 4.3

```
Build time:   2017-10-30 15:43:29 UTC
Revision:     c684c202534c4138b51033b52d871939b8d38d72

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 x86
```

I haven't installed Ant but I see that it comes with Gradle.
So what am I missing?

Comment: why would you care? you can use printlin or log() to output things from gradle.  don't mix in ant.

Comment: yes I know but I was just experimenting with a tutorial and that didn't work.